# How can I get gcc to warn me about "int i = i;"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, std, compiler-warnings

A simple program:

```
int main()
{
    long i = i;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling as C gives no errors and no warnings.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic 1.c
```

Compiling as C++ gives a warning:

```
$ c++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic 1.c
1.c: In function ‘int main()’:
1.c:3:7: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  long i = i;
```

In both cases variable i seems to be 0, although in c++ it could be uninitialized. I actually made such a typo in one of my functions and it was quite hard to find it. What can I do to avoid this? I'd expect at least a warning. Moreover, Clang doesn't give any warning in either case (c or c++). Is there a specific part of the standard that says anything about this behavior?

Edit: Having tried something similar:

```
$ cat 1.c
int main(void)
{
    int k = k + 0;
    int i = i + 1;
    return 0;
}
```

The warning (in C) is generated only for "i".

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra 1.c
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:4:6: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  int i = i + 1;
```

Comment: C is generally OK with trash values, but this is kind-of surprising, especially after having worked with Python for so long (I'm expecting a NameError :)).

Comment: Warnings are a "quality of implementation" issue. The standard tells nothing about them.

Comment: I think the best the standard could say is that uninitialized reads (for anything other than unsigned byte types) are undefined in C++, while they might be unspecified in C? I'm not sure about the latter

Comment: @KABoissonneault it's still undefined behaviour in C.  Since uninitialized variables in C have garbage data, it's unpredictable as to what will result will be in doing such an operation, or even when said variable is used in the RHS of a statement.

Comment: @Tau I'm not sure it is UB in C, it's `main()` not `main(void)` thus it's technically AFAIK still legal to pass a value to that function (although that should be prototyped). But I'd have to leave that to language lawyers.

Comment: It compiles because C & C++'s rules are simply not strict enough or good enough. Non-ancient languages do not allow such constructs.

Comment: "unpredictable data" is a form of unspecified behavior. Undefined behavior means there's absolutely no restrictions on what the implementation can do

Comment: The compiler is not required to post diagnostic messages if the program invokes undefined behavior. As for why gcc behaves inconsistent here, I have no idea. `long i = i++;` gives a warning "‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function" but `long i = i;` does not. This is mighty strange. Smells like some kind of optimization, given that `i = i` should be optimized to `i`. Adding a volatile qualifier doesn't change anything though, as it ought to if optimization was the culprit, so I'm leaning towards a compiler bug.

Comment: Notably, if we ignore the value being indeterminate, I think `i = i;` is well-defined behavior as far as sequencing goes, in C++17 and beyond. Perhaps that's why?

Comment: @Lundin the assignment `i = i` is a no-op, but `int i = i;` is not an assignment, it means something completely different. It's very intentional that `int i = i;` doesn't warn, see the GCC docs for `-Winit-self`. Self-initialization is a traditional C idiom for avoiding uninitialized warnings, so GCC doesn't warn by default.

Comment: @Mgetz what has `main()` vs `main(void)` got to do with this question? In any case, and empty parameter list on a function definition means it takes no arguments. It only means it can take any number of arguments when `()` is used in a prototype, not in a definition.

Comment: @JonathanWakely recall your K&R in C without the `void` the number of parameters is _unspecified_ not none. It's not a useful feature... but it is a legacy "Feature" of C.

Comment: @Mgetz it would be undefined to pass a value to `main()` http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_317.htm

Comment: @JonathanWakely I'm aware of the standard there is a reason I said K&R. Which most compilers still subtly support even in the newest modes... you of course are empowered to fix that ;)

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's mostly just a formality, since C doesn't have any constructors. Rather, it is _exactly_ the same thing as assignment, as we can read in the C language standard 6.7.9 §11 "the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply". As for self-initialization, I would hardly call it a "traditional idiom", but bug-prone obfuscation. As we can see from this very question; the reason the OP asked is because gcc caused a bug for not warning about trashy code. And none of it explains why g++ does warn.

Comment: @Mgetz An empty parenthesis is an obsolete feature in C and should not be used. Since C99: "The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature." In addition, `int main()` is not one of the forms of a conforming hosted implementation needs to accept, but an implementation-defined form. In C++ however, `()` is fine and often stylistically preferred over `(void)`.

Comment: i don't see this clearly mentioned yet, but `int i = i;` is legal in C and the same as `int i;`,  but causes undefined behaviour in C++ (use of indeterminate value)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For GCC compiling C programs, you need to add the compiler flag `-Winit-self`. (You also need `-Wall` or `-Wuninitialized`, see below.) For GCC compiling C++ programs, this flag is implied by `-Wall` but for C it needs to specified explicitly; it is not part of `-Wextra` either.

For Clang, the situation is slightly more interesting. In the snippet in the OP, Clang does not produce any diagnostic. However, with the slightly different snippet supplied in the GCC manual below, a diagnostic is provided:

```
int f() {
  int i = i;
  return i;
}
```

The difference is that in the above snippet, the (uninitialized) value of `i` is actually used. Apparently, in the original code Clang detected that the variable was useless and eliminated it as dead code before applying the diagnostic.

In Clang, the diagnostic is triggered by `-Wuninitialized`, which is enabled by `-Wall` as in GCC.

---

Here's an excerpt from the GCC manual:

> **`-Winit-self` (C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ only)**
>
> Warn about uninitialized variables that are initialized with themselves.  Note this option can only be used with the `-Wuninitialized` option.
>
> For example, GCC warns about `i` being uninitialized in the following snippet only when `-Winit-self` has been specified:
>
> ```
>         int f()
>           {
>             int i = i;
>             return i;
>           }
> ```
>
> This warning is enabled by `-Wall` in C++.

As the excerpt indicates, `-Wuninitialized` is also required. In both C and C++, `-Wall` implies `-Wuninitialized`. However, note that many uninitialized uses will not be detected unless some optimization level is also requested. (That doesn't apply to `-Winit-self`, as far as I know. It can be detected without optimization.)

---

Irritatingly, when you unmark a question as a duplicate, the previously-marked duplicates disappear. I unmarked it because none of the duplicates actually answered the question in the body; I also edited the title.

For reference, here are the original duplicates, which may be of interest:

- [Why does the compiler allow initializing a variable with itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110546/why-does-the-compiler-allow-initializing-a-variable-with-itself)
- [gcc failing to warn of uninitialized variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705880/gcc-failing-to-warn-of-uninitialized-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Why is this initialization accepted by the c++ compiler? static int x = x;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841171/why-is-this-initialization-accepted-by-the-c-compiler-static-int-x-x)
- [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415661/has-c-standard-changed-with-respect-to-the-use-of-indeterminate-values-and-und)

Comment: What is the sense of a warning that you have to discover yourself prior to using a compiler option?  The boys of gcc sometimes do things somewhat tricky!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

It is basically:

```
int i;
i = i;
```

in which `i` is an uninitialized value.

Comment: This seems quite probable. However if you do "int i = i + 0;" there's no warning, while gcc warn of uninitialized value when you do "int i = i + 1". Is there a way to circumvent such issues?

Comment: @notnonuninvisible - What issue? Other than this most trivial of cases GCC warns you about using the value of an uninitialized variable. Avoiding the trivial case is easy: people should read what they type.

Comment: @StoryTeller - I get your point, however there's a point we have syntax rules and compilers. Typing is not the only way to get into such a problem - think of e.g. merging code.

Comment: @notnonuninvisible - C and C++ are not, and never were "safe languages". There is little point in contorting a compiler to protect against every conceivable human error. That's the whole reason UB is a thing in those languages.

Comment: Just a nitpick: initialization and assignment have different rules - they may not always be the same - this case is a simplification.

Comment: @StoryTeller I also understand what you're saying now. I would like to understand and discuss the underlying reason. Just saying "C is bad" and marking it a duplicate doesnt' help me understand or discuss it.

Comment: how does this answer the question? There is a warning along the line of "variable i may be used uninitialized" and the compiler could show this warning

Comment: @notnonuninvisible - I didn't say "bad". I said "not safe". It's not one and the same. Lack of safety is also power, because nothing is encumbering you with safety nets you don't need. And I'm sorry, but discussing this philosophical point is off-topic.The only on-topic point of is it allowed is answered in the dupe, which I believe I aptly chose.

Comment: @StoryTeller The dupe drags in c# which I don't care about. I extended my question to include case where it's uninitialized plus a defined value, which then should follow some defined order of evaluation (values and types). So in the end the question is rather: "why the existing warning is not emitted in an obvious case", not "is C safe/bad", etc.

Comment: @notnonuninvisible - "*some defined order of evaluation*" is again an assumption on your part about the nature of C and C++. For some constructs, it doesn't exist. And again, that's beside the point. Making your question broader (again, making it more off-topic) is not helping it. But we digress. If you manage to convince a gold-badge holder in the C or C++ tags to re-open, they will. I'm out.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok, I get it. It's not the place to discuss programming matters, but policies and policeman. However I still do not know why "for some constructs it doesn't exist" if such a warning was designed for similar cases. I still don't know why I shouldn't assume that warning to be emitted. You only pointed me into thinking that asking questions and discussing compiler warnings is off-topic and I shouldn't ask. That's sad.

Comment: @notnonuninvisible didnt follow all your discussion, though you shouldnt assume any warning to be emitted. If they were that reliable they probably were errors not warnings. Warnings is like the compiler holding your hand to avoid some pitfalls, but you should not rely on it. The standard does not mandate anything about warnings afaik, so if you really want to know on the compiler level why there is no warning in this case you would have to study gcc internals (not the language specifications)

Comment: This discussion is way off topic. It should be continued in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180743/notnonuninvisible-discussion).

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to answer the question, which is, "How can I get gcc to warn me about 'int i=i;'"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: That's partly my fault. I edited the question's title, which was misleading. In the original post, the question "How can I get a warning" was the actual question asked, but it was not at all obvious without reading. See the note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The combination of `-Wall -Winit-self` seems to add this diagnostic:

```
$ gcc -Wall      -Winit-self t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:3:10: warning: ‘i’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     long i = i;
          ^
```

Comment: Specifically, it's enabled by `-Wuninitialized -Winit-self` (the former is enabled by `-Wall`)